# Error in date while formatting in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Hi I am trying to format date which I m getting from server. I have tryed like this

```
NSString *dateStr =@"2012-5-21";
    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];


    // Convert date object to desired output format
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
                                dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
    finalDate.text=dateStr;


    [dateFormat release];
```

but in place of `21 May 2012`. I am getting `21 Jan 2012`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are using wrong format first time. mm is for Minutes , replace it with capital MM -

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

Answer (score 4):

USe Capital MM for month format representaion

```
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

Comment: Already same answer with same solution was given.. Please do not duplicate answers..